# Memory management in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to understand the memory management concepts in Cocoa.
I am stuck at the following portion:::

```
//This is wrong code. But i want to understand why it is wrong!  
- (void) setEngine: (Engine *) newEngine  
{  
      [engine release];  
      engine = [newEngine retain];  
}
```

When newEngine and engine are same, then how does cocoa decides which one to be treated as an instance variable and which one as a parameter?

For example:

```
Engine *engine = [Engine new]; // count: 1  
Car *car1 = [Car new];  
Car *car2 = [Car new]; 

[car1 setEngine: engine]; // count: 2 -----How is the retain count 2 here? 
[engine release]; // count 1 

[car2 setEngine: [car1 engine]];
```

Please help as i want to learn this concept thoroughly so as to maintain efficiency in my programs.  I am sure a lot many are stuck at this as me and my friends are.. Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: You can use the "{}" icon to format code. Also, the framework name is "Cocoa" not COCOA (it's not an acronym).

Comment: Alright..will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you want to make sure your setter is checking to see if the objects are different:

```
- (void)setEngine:(Engine *)newEngine {
    if ( engine != newEngine ) {
        [engine release];
        [newEngine retain];
        engine = newEngine;
    }
}
```

Here's what happens inside this method:

1. Check to see that the engine that has been passed in is different to the one we already have. If it is the same, nothing needs to be done.
2. Release the *old* engine. If we were the last object to own it, its retain count will be zero and it will be deallocated. If the old engine was `nil`, then the `release` message will simply be ignored.
3. Retain the *new* engine. If it is released somewhere else, it will not be deallocated because we have taken ownership of it. If the new engine is `nil`, then the `retain` message will simply be ignored.
4. Set the `engine` instance variable to `newEngine`.

Secondly, the reason that the retain count is two after you call `setEngine:` is because it started as 1 when it was created. Then you assigned it to car1, which retained it, bringing the retain count to 2. The retain count is two because your outer code owns it *and* car1 owns it. You should pass it to car1 and car2 in the same way (`[car2 setEngine:car]`) which would bring the retain count to 3. Once you have passed it along to car1 and car2, you can release it it your outer code - this tells Obcjective-C that your outer code no longer owns it, the ownership lies only with car1 and car2.

Here's a full example:

```
// create an engine, we will own it for now
Engine *engine = [[Engine alloc] init];

/* engine retain count: 1, owned by this context */

Car *car1 = [[Car alloc] init];
Car *car2 = [[Car alloc] init];

// pass engine along to cars
[car1 setEngine: engine];
[car2 setEngine: engine];

/* engine retain count: 3, owned by car1, car2 and this context */

// release engine, we no longer need it
[engine release];

/* engine retain count: 2, owned by car1 and car2 */
```

Comment: Thnx Simon for the answer...I understood so far as u explained...However i still am not clear as to how the execution of the setEngine takes place?  Like in the same example:- (void) setEngine: (Engine *) newEngine
{
[engine release];//first engine is released...which engine?? instance variable or the object created outside the method?
engine = [newEngine retain];
}

Comment: I added a description of what is happening inside `setEngine:`.

Comment: Does that mean that the setter method also causes increase in the retain count of an object? I ask so because when engine is passed as a parameter to the setter method, it is retained by car1.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what is confusing you. Initially the engine property is nil because it has not been set yet. This means that when you call `[engine release]` you are actually calling `[nil release]`. This may seem strange, but there is actually nothing wrong with it. You can call any method on `nil` and it will simply ignore it. So the first time you call `release` inside the setter, it is being ignored. Likewise, if you were to call `setEngine:nil` then it would call `retain` on `nil`, also ignored.

Comment: Wow!! i dint know that.........Thanks for the info :D...Yet another thing now that is troubling me...The code that u sent, we are first checking if the two are same, if yes, we dont retain it...So then how does the retain count of engine increase?

Comment: Like I mentioned, when you first call `setEngine:`, the car's `engine` property is `nil`, so when we ask `if (engine != newEngine)` we're actually asking `if (nil != newEngine)`. The answer is `YES`, so the setter will release `nil` (ignored) and retain `newEngine` (bringing its retain count to 2). Make sense?

Comment: You said "we are first checking if the two are same". No, we're checking to see if they are different. If they are different (or if our property is `nil`) then we do the swap.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a tonne :D     At least this concept wont scare me anymore....i have a lot clearer concepts now :)

Comment: No problem. This stuff seems really hard at first, but you get used to it really fast. By the way, I edited my answer so that i'm using `alloc` and `init` instead of `new`. Same thing, just more conventional.